# Как убрать NaN из столбца?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Мне надо отправить файл без NaN в столбцах, вместо NaN должны быть значения  0 или 1

```
Submission_x = pd.read_csv(f'/content/Submission.csv', index_col = 0)
Submission_x['polution_clf'] = test_target_df
timestamp = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
Submission_x.to_csv(f'/content/Submission_y.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
res = df.groupby(["polution_clf"]).first().reset_index()
Submission_x
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Примените метод [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
Submission_x = Submission_x.fillna(0)
```

чтобы изменить все `NaN` значения на нули, или

```
Submission_x = Submission_x.fillna(1)
```

для изменения на единицы.